# Node.js | WHATWG URL Query Parameter Key Parsing - How to Have It Not Parsed?

Tags: node.js, linkedin-api, urlencode

I'm using the [WHATWG API for URLs in Node.js (v10.x)](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/url.html#url_url_strings_and_url_objects).

I have a URL query parameter that has a key that is supposed to have a `[` and a `]`. 
When they're included in they key, like so:

```
// creates new URLSearchParams, and adds them to an existing URL

myURL //existing `URL` object

let search_params = new URLSearchParams({
    companies[0]: <my_value_here>
});
myURL.search = search_params.toString();
```

Then `myURL.href` includes this query parameter key-value pair
`companies%5B0%5D=<my_value_here>`

I want to have the key not URL-encoded. Is there a way to prevent the encoding of the key/those characters specifically, or alternatively, URL-decode the key?
I prefer disabling the encodig for that key (and preferably any desired key, and value, potentially, too).

This is for LinkedIn's Marketing Analytics APIs, if anyone has experience with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the API actually break when you pass encoded `[]` characters? If so, then that's a bug in the API and it really should be fixed by LinkedIn and not worked around by you.

That said, you could manually decode those specific characters.

```
myURL.search = search_params.toString();
const myURLHackForLinkedIn = myURL.toString().replace(/%5B0%5D/g, "[]");
```

I wouldn't be surprised if a browser re-encoded them behind the scenes when you passed them over HTTP though.

Comment: Which API? LinkedIn's?

Comment: @GalGrünfeld — Yes, that's why I said LinkedIn should fix it.

Comment: They have a lot more to fix with their API .
But in any case, this is out of the scope of the question. 

Thanks for the solution, though. I'm preferring disabling the encoding rather than adding additional code. I'm not marking it as an answer to see if there are solutions that fit my preference better.

Comment: Yes, it "breaks" the API - LinkedIn's API is expecting a key of a specific structure and since `.search`'s setter percent-encodes the values automatically then the resulting URLSearchParameters members are percent-encoded. And I have no control over `.search`'s behavior.